# Looping and variables in a batch file

Tags: for-loop, dos, batch-file

I want to read only first two lines in a batch file and store them in two different variables. I used this code:

```
@echo off 

for /f "delims=''" %%f in (red.txt) do (

echo file is: %%f

set /A Counter+=1
call :a %counter%
echo Counter After Increment: %Counter%
echo.
)
:a
if %Counter% equ 1 (set "file1=%f"
echo first file is: %file1%)

if %Counter% equ 2 (set "file2=%f"
echo second file is: %file2%)

if %Counter% equ 4 exit
echo Counter after for loop: %Counter%

pause
```

but variables 'file1' and 'file2' show blank.
Any thought on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try is a bit overkill and the syntax is wrong.

Try this instead

```
<red.txt (
  set /p line1=
  set /p line2=
)
echo line1=%line1% 
echo line2=%line2%
```